# How to call a function that simplifies a fraction in C?

Tags: c, function, data-structures, struct, fractions

This is what I need to do:

Define a structure called “fraction” with integer members “numerator” and
“denominator.” Prompt the user to enter a fraction in the form “#/#”. Call a function called
“simplFrac” that simplifies a fraction by dividing the numerator and denominator by the greatest
common factor and returns the simplified fraction to the calling function. Print the results from
main().

And here is my code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  struct fraction {
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
  };

  struct fraction simplFrac(struct fraction x);

 int main(void) {

  struct fraction a;

  printf("Enter a fraction in the form #/#: ");
  scanf("%i/%i",&a.numerator,&a.denominator);

  printf("\n");

  printf("The simplified fraction is: %i/%i\n",);

  return 0;
 }

struct fraction simplFrac(struct fraction x) {
  
  int gcf,remainder;

  while (x.numerator != 0)
   {
      remainder = x.denominator % x.numerator;
      x.denominator = x.numerator;
      x.numerator = remainder;
   }

   gcf = x.denominator;

   x.numerator = x.numerator / gcf;
   x.denominator = x.denominator / gcf;

   return x;
}
```

Comment: That's some code, but what's the problem?

Comment: `struct fraction result; result = simplFrac(a);`.  Other variants are possible (declare and initialize in the same statement, assign the result back to `a`, etc) just like any other function that returns a value.

Comment: I don't think your algorithm for `simplFrac` is correct though; I think it will always return `0/1`.  Try stepping through it mentally with some examples.

Comment: Read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and the documentation of your C compiler, e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Take inspiration from existing open source C code like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) - you are allowed to download that code and study it (and even improve it). Use of course the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct fraction
{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
};

struct fraction simplFrac(struct fraction x);
int gcf(int, int);

int main(void)
{
    struct fraction a;
    char buf[BUFSIZ];

    printf("Enter a fraction in the form #/#: ");
    fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, stdin);
    sscanf(buf, "%i/%i", &a.numerator, &a.denominator);

    a = simplFrac(a);

    printf("The simplified fraction is: %i/%i\n", a.numerator, a.denominator);

    return 0;
}

struct fraction simplFrac(struct fraction x)
{
    int factor = gcf(x.denominator, x.numerator);

    x.numerator /=  factor;
    x.denominator /= factor;

    return x;
}

int gcf(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0) return a;
    else return gcf(b, a % b);
}
```

The algorythm to calculate the gcf is separated as a function gcf().